# Imagic text-transform to uppercase

Tags: php, css, imagick

How to set text-transform to uppercase with imagic?

```
 $draw = new ImagickDraw();
               $draw->setFont( $this->fontfoder . "IMPACT.TTF" );
               $draw->setFontSize( 196 );
               $draw->setGravity( $textgravity );
               $draw->setFillColor( $black );
               $draw->setStrokeColor('#000000 ');
               $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
```

This is the draw with normal letters.

Comment: You can probably use/get away with [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

Comment: I don't believe there's any support for `text-transform` in `ImagickDraw`. You'll have to uppercase the text before drawing, or find an "all-caps" font library. Maybe [Bebas](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Bebas)?